# GRE question. What is the meaning of "irregular" here?

Tags: meaning, gre

Pick two words that each fit in the blank and results in the sentence having the same meaning.

> The__________ nature of the room was considered extraordinary by
>   everyone, even Tamika who realized she was cleaning her own apartment
>   at increasingly irregular intervals.

- inscrutable
- purified
- sanitized
- squalid
- transient
- sullied

I picked sanitized and purified. But why does "irregular" suggest that the room here is dirty and not really clean? Can't "irregular" mean that it occurs less often than usual instead of more often?

Comment: Did  you look at the definitions for all the words? I can see two others that are synonyms . . .

Comment: One could stretch it a bit and pick "squalid" and "sullied", though one would not normally use "sullied" to describe a room.  (But one wouldn't normally use "purified", "sanitized", or "transient" either.)

Comment: @HotLicks: Thanks for disturbing the "teaching moment" . . .

Comment: (And "irregular" means "not regular".  Ie, at intervals that randomly vary in length.)

Comment: @Robusto - I was typing.

Comment: No matter. This question is OT anyway.

Comment: @Robusto - Not only that, the (GRE) question is stupid.  (And, at the very least, it lacks critical context.  Eg, *what* room are we talking about?)

Comment: @Robusto I agree with HotLicks

Comment: Why do I have a -1 for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with squalid and sullied. Tamika is turning into a slob, but ***EVEN*** she considers the room extraordinary. If you go with sanitized and purified, then the use of "even" comes off strange. Why is so surprising that a slob-in-the-making is impressed by a clean room? But if the room is messy, THEN it makes sense that EVEN our resident slob finds the room extraordinary.

"Can't "irregular" mean that it occurs less often than usual instead of more often?"

Yes. In fact, I'd think that it was MORE likely that the implication is that Tamika is cleaning her room less and less often. If you clean it more and more often, pretty soon you're cleaning it every day, which would be very regularly indeed! But if you are cleaning it less and less often, then the intervals between cleanings can more easily vary.

Again, she's turning into a slob, but EVEN she finds the nature of the room extraordinary, which says to me that this place is a cesspool (i.e., squalid and sullied).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Upvoted. Are you taking the GRE soon? If so, good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Well theoretically, in order to have increasingly irregular intervals over a long period of time, the localized frequency will decrease (time in between cleanings would increase). This would result in a higher likelihood that the room is dirty at any given moment that you choose to enter the room.

So if the cleaning schedule was on increasingly irregular intervals then the room would be dirty for a larger percentage of the time than previously (in the general case).